# Any idea how this can be read as a CSV? - Python

Tags: python, excel, sqlite, csv

I have a CSV formatted in the following way:

> ID=123[DLE]KEY=test[DLE]KEY2=VAL123

where [DLE] is the ["Data link escape" control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes)

---

**Any idea how I could use this with the csv standard library?**

Do I need to edit each row in order to make it compatible?

#### Edit: my main problem is the "KEY=VALUE" formatting

Thanks guys

Comment: Are the keys always in the same order?

Answer (score 5):

Your data is not actually in CSV format, so I'd give up on trying to use it. What I'd do is write a generator that took each line, did `.split('\x10')`, and then did `.split('=', 1)` on each piece, and then yielded the whole thing as a dict.

```
def dgen(fin):
  for line in fin:
    yield dict(((k, v) for chunk in line.rstrip('\r\n').split('\x10')
        for (k, v) in chunk.split('=', 1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse it by simply overriding the delimiter (pretend the snowman is your DLE):

```
import csv
testdata='ID=123☃KEY=test☃KEY2=VAL123\nID=456☃KEY=test2☃KEY2=val456'
testdataiter=testdata.splitlines()
reader = csv.reader(testdataiter, delimiter='☃')
for row in reader:
    print (','.join(row))
```

outputs:

```
ID=123,KEY=test,KEY2=VAL123
ID=456,KEY=test2,KEY2=val456
```

Check the help for the csv module - any of the dialect parameters can be overriden in the reader constructor.

---

To parse your KEY=VAL into a dict, change to:

```
...
for row in reader:
    rowdict = dict([x.split('=',1) for x in row])
    print rowdict
```

outputs:

```
{'KEY2': 'VAL123', 'ID': '123', 'KEY': 'test'}
{'KEY2': 'val456', 'ID': '456', 'KEY': 'test2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can pass the `csv` module a format character ([csv module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader)):

```
>>> import csv
>>> spamReader = csv.reader(open('eggs.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
>>> fields = ["ID","KEY","KEY2"]
>>> mydict = csv.DictReader(open("csv.txt","rbU"),delimiter=chr(16),fieldnames=field
s)
>>> mylist = [line for line in mydict]
>>> mylist
[{'KEY2': 'KEY2=VAL123', 'ID': 'ID=123', 'KEY': 'KEY=test'}]
```

Edit: Better answer given above

Answer (score 0):

```
reader = csv.reader(open(datafile, "rb"), delimiter=chr(16))
data = (dict(tuple(i.split("=") for i in row)) for row in reader)
```

Will give you a generator. You can turn it into a list or a tuple.

```
data_list = list(data)
```

Which would be a list of dicts.

```
[{'ID': '123', 'KEY': 'test', 'KEY2': 'VAL123'},
 {'ID': '456', 'KEY': 'test2', 'KEY2': 'val456'}]
```